# Intuition underlying stopped martingales

Tags: stochastic-processes, self-learning, brownian-motion, martingales, stochastic-analysis

Let $X$ be a martingale and $T$ a stopping time. Define the stopped martingale $X_{\min\{T,n\}}$. What is the intuition underlying this process? It is quite confusing here. $X$ is random and $T$ is also random and depends on $X$. Then what does one get putting two together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gambler's Ruin example is probably helpful for intuition. Consider a Markov chain $X_n$ whose state space is the integers which jumps 1 unit to the left or to the right with equal probability. Now let $\tau = \inf \{ n : X_n = 0 \}$. Then the stopped process is the same as the original process until the gambler runs out of money, after which he presumably leaves the casino. By contrast, in the original process, the gambler would be allowed to play into debt rather than stopping when he went bankrupt.

Comment: So in your example, at any given $n$, the value for $X_{\min\{T, n\}}$ is $0$ if $T$ is realized and other non-zero integer otherwise. Right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "$T$ is realized". $X$ is $0$ if $T \leq n$. Otherwise $X$ is a positive integer (provided the process starts at a nonnegative integer, of course). It may be clearer to make the dependence on $\omega$ explicit: we are really considering $(\omega,n) \mapsto X_{\min \{ T(\omega),n \}}(\omega)$.

Comment: Hey Ian, why have you defined $\tau = \inf\{n: X_n = 0\}$ instead of simply as a $\min$ ?

Comment: @elbarto Usually $\min$ is fine in discrete time, except in the case where the event in question never happens. Then the $\inf$ takes care of it by assigning the stopping time the value $+\infty$ (through the usual convention $\inf \emptyset = +\infty$).